# icefaces outputConnectionStatus in javascript

Tags: icefaces

I would like to reload the page when the connection with the server is dropped or timed out.

I am not seeing any alerts in any of the following call backs.

```
    ice.onConnectionLost('document:body', function() { 
        alert('Connection lost!'); 
    }); 


          ice.onNetworkError(networkErrorHandler);
          var networkErrorHandler = function(statusCode, errorDescription) {
            alert('onNetworkError.. ');
    };

    ice.onBlockingConnectionUnstable(connectionUnstableHandler);
    var connectionUnstableHandler = function() {
        alert('onBlockingConnectionUnstable.. ');
    };

    ice.onBlockingConnectionLost(connectionLostHandler);
    var connectionLostHandler = function(reconnectionAttempts) {
        alert('onBlockingConnectionLost.. ');
    };

    ice.onBlockingConnectionServerError(serverErrorHandler);
    var serverErrorHandler = function(statusCode, responseText, responseDOM) {
        alert('onBlockingConnectionServerError.. ');
    };


          ice.onSessionExpired('document:body', function() {
        //location.reload(true);
        alert('onSessionExpired.. ');
    });
    ice.onServerError('document:body', function() {
        //location.reload(true);
        alert('onServerError.. ');
    });
    ice.onConnectionTrouble('document:body', function() {
        //location.reload(true);
        alert('onConnectionTrouble.. ');
    });
    ice.onConnectionLost('document:body', function() {
        //location.reload(true);
        alert('onConnectionLost.. ');
    });
```

First, I am not understanding why my event is not getting trapped in any of above callbacks ( I have reduced com.icesoft.faces.connectionTimeout to 10 sec, to simulate 'disconnectedLabel=="Disconnected. Please retry."' in ice:outputConnectionStatus)

Is there anyway I can ask for connection status on demand? Like, running a javascript every @10 sec and asking for ConnectionStatus. Depending on connection status, I want to reload the page.

Thanks

Comment: I have a similar problem getting connection timeout to work, Icefaces really isn't clear to my mind.